# In Groovy, how do I add up the values for a certain property in a map?

Tags: groovy

I have the following map:

```
def map = [];
map.add([ item: "Shampoo", count: 5 ])
map.add([ item: "Soap", count: 3 ])
```

I would like to get the sum of all the `count` properties in the map. In C# using LINQ, it would be something like:

```
map.Sum(x => x.count)
```

How do I do the same in Groovy?

Comment: Please check you code - it looks wrong to me. E.g. "add" method usually used on lists not maps. 3rd line is missing "count:" key?

Comment: This code is invalid. Check it in groovy console.

Comment: Whoops, this is what happens when you type a question as you're heading out the door :).

Comment: [Greatings could someone please help me out with this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43314494/count-objects-in-an-each-loop-with-groovy)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Assuming you have a list like so:

```
List list = [ [item: "foo", count: 5],
              [item: "bar", count: 3] ]
```

Then there are multiple ways of doing it.  The most readable is probably

```
int a = list.count.sum()
```

Or you could use the Closure form of sum on the whole list

```
int b = list.sum { it.count }
```

Or you could even use a more complex route such as inject

```
int c = list.count.inject { tot, ele -> tot + ele } // Groovy 2.0
//  c = list.count.inject( 0 ) { tot, ele -> tot + ele } // Groovy < 2.0
```

All of these give the same result.

```
assert ( a == b ) && ( b == c ) && ( c == 8 )
```

I would use the first one.

Comment: Thanks, that was easier than I thought.

Comment: Use as bigdecimal for Object based sum

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the `collect` operator. I checked the following code with groovysh:

```
list1 = []
total = 0
list1[0] = [item: "foo", count: 5]
list1[1] = [item: "bar", count: 3]
list1.collect{ total += it.count }
println "total = ${total}"
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you're confusing map and list syntax in your example. Anyhow, Groovy injects a [.sum(closure)](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#sum%28groovy.lang.Closure%29) method to all collections.

Example:

```
[[a:1,b:2], [a:5,b:4]].sum { it.a }
===> 6
```