# count objects in an each loop with groovy

Tags: grails, groovy

```
def numbers = [[duration:1, calldate:6, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:6, disposition:1], [duration:2, calldate:7, disposition:2], [duration:2, calldate:7, disposition:2], [duration:1, calldate:7, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:7, disposition:1], [duration:2, calldate:7, disposition:2], [duration:2, calldate:7, disposition:2], [duration:2, calldate:7, disposition:2], [duration:1, calldate:7, disposition:1], [duration:2, calldate:7, disposition:2], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:2, calldate:8, disposition:2], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:2, calldate:8, disposition:2], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:2, calldate:8, disposition:2], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:2, calldate:8, disposition:2], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:2, calldate:8, disposition:2], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1], [duration:1, calldate:8, disposition:1]]

numbers.eachWithIndex { item, i ->


println "${numbers[i]} calldate: ${item.calldate} Duration:         ${item.duration}  Disposition: ${item.disposition}"

        };
```

I need to count objects from duration and disposition but the call date has to be unique

Comment: Can you provide expected output?

Answer (score 1):

```
numbers.groupBy {
   it.calldate
}.sort().each{
  def duration = (it.value*.duration).sum()
  def disposition = (it.value*.disposition).sum()
  println "$it.key $duration $disposition"
}
```

Output:

```
  6 2 2
  7 15 15
  8 94 94
```